# how to start page-scraping technique

Tags: html, xml, rss

I'm new to page scraping, and i don't know where to start.
What is easiest way to do page scraping? What are your opinions for that, what web technologies are best for that?
Can anyone help me, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well probably best and easiset way would be with yahoo query language YQL.
It's simple to use. U can also use yahoo pipes with yql. Google it.
You can begin here:
http://ijaar.com/basic-yql-tutorials/

Also there are some question about screen scraping here on stack so check it out.

And yes, yql is not the only technique for that, you can also use php, xquery, even python for that, but in my opinion it's the easiest - and it works really fine.

Comment: @dmaster no problem, but as Andrew said be more specific in your questions and give exact problem

Answer (score 0):

Look into [html aglity pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/);

Example:

Well, it depends. If, for example, one tag has a class and it is unique- it is one function, but if there are multiple tags, you need to think and create your function based on tag location, another situation when there are no tags and you would have to count html elements; you might also need to loop over tabe rows for example.

Example below does similar what you need. (not sure if it still works, since if there was a change in the page layout, it might fail.) But it gives the idea and you can go from there.

PS - when asking questions please give exact problem, not the vague question.

**C# Example:**

```
                String openUrl = @"http://www.ebay.com/sch/-/11724/i.html?_nkw=" + some_part_number + "&_armrs=1&LH_Complete=1";

                HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
                hw.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(openUrl);

                foreach (HtmlNode nd in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@itemprop='offers']"))
                {
                    String title = "";
                    title = Regex.Split(nd.InnerHtml.ToString(), ("title='"))[1].Trim();
                    title = Regex.Split(title, "'")[0].Trim();
                }
```

Comment: sorry for not giving exact problem, i am new to stack overflow so i need to get use to it. Thank you for your effort!